# Laravel Composer package won't install

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php

I'm trying to install Zizaco in Laravel. (https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust)
When I add `"zizaco/entrust": "dev-laravel-5"` to require and then exec composer update in cmd it's saying nothing to install or update.

This is my entire composer.json file :

```
{
    "name": "classpreloader/classpreloader",
    "description": "Helps class loading performance by generating a single PHP file containing all of the autoloaded files for a specific use case",
    "keywords": ["autoload", "class", "preload"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Michael Dowling",
            "email": "mtdowling@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "Graham Campbell",
            "email": "graham@alt-three.com"
        }
    ],
    "require":{
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "nikic/php-parser": "~1.3",
        "zizaco/entrust": "dev-laravel-5"
    },

    "require-dev":{
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "ClassPreloader\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": ["tests/stubs/"]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.0-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here>>?

Thanks

EDIT ---

De documentation is telling me this:

In order to install Entrust, we just need to add this line to the composer.json file:

```
"zizaco/entrust": "dev-laravel-5"
1
You should have something like this:

"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*",
   "zizaco/entrust": "dev-laravel-5"
},

Next, run composer update to install Entrust.
```

Comment: What happens if you do `composer remove zizaco/entrust`.

Comment: Package "zizaco/entrust" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring. Loading composer repositories with package information updating dependencies...... Strange because I dit require it?

Comment: Are you sure the package is available to **5.1**?

Answer (score 1):

There is a comma(`,`) missing.

correct it :

```
"require":{
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "nikic/php-parser": "~1.3", 
    "zizaco/entrust": "dev-laravel-5"
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it's still saying "Nothing to install or update"

Comment: try to clear cache and compiled classes: `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan clear-compiled` then update it

Comment: Oh, missed `"laravel/framework": "5.1.*",` thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma after **"nikic/php-parser": "~1.3"**

Your composer.json should contain:

```
"require":{
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "nikic/php-parser": "~1.3",
    "zizaco/entrust": "dev-laravel-5"
},
```

Comment: Thanks but it won't install

Comment: Run composer validate to confirm there are no other typos

Comment: Did you try composer update or only composer install?

Comment: Tried it both I also tried to clear the cache. But still not working :(

Comment: Pardon my question, but are you surę there is no such package in vendors already? :)

Comment: Yes I'm sure about that.

Comment: Make sure you update the question when you find out why it didnt work. i'd love to know the reason :)